# Vuforia Add/Delete Images In Device Databases - Target Manager Programmatically

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to change (add|delete) the target image. So, I have to change the current device database or create a new device database and download the xml and the dat file from the **Target Manager**.

---

I have achieved the same in **Metaio**, but due to the unavailability of free license for commercial purposes, I have decided to use **Vuforia SDK**.

---

My question is

- *IS THERE A WAY TO PROGRAMMATICALLY DOWNLOAD THE NEW XML AND THE DAT FILE SUCH THAT I CAN ADD | DELETE NEW IMAGES TO TARGET IMAGE LIST?*

xml file can be recreated but what about the dat file? Any leads on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes its possible i have achieved this by storing all data like texture dat and xml in sd card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the free license only allows you to manage your images via the Target Manager then download the dataset (.xml and .dat) manually and package them with your app.

If you want to add / remove images from this dataset, you'd have to go to the Target Manager, add / remove images, then re-download the dataset (.xml and .data) and replace the old ones in your app manually.

Only the Cloud license allows managing the dataset programatically.

Vuforia Pricing: https://developer.vuforia.com/pricing

Comment: Yes, I had the same findings. Anyway thanks for your answer